# Issue with querying database using LINQ query to bring list of DTO

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a LINQ query in the below format. The problem is that I am passing a list of 100 `consumerID` in the form of list. I want to query the database and bring result for 
all these 100 consumerIds. However the query brings back the result only for the first guy. I am suspecting I am missing something in the where clause. I am sure there are matching results in the database for all these 100 consumerIds.

```
public ICollection<ConsumerExchangeChangeDto> GetByConsumers(List<int> consumerIDs)
{
    EnrollmentReportingModel db = (EnrollmentReportingModel)Context.DbContext;
    var results = (from ecew in db.A
        join ecewe in db.B on ecew.ID 
        equals ecewe.ExchangeChangeEnrollmentWindowID into temp
        from j in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join cecr in db.C on ecew.ConsumerExchangeChangeRequestID equals cecr.ID
        join con in db.D on cecr.ConsumerID equals con.ID
        where consumerIDs.Contains(con.ID) && !ecew.Deleted
        select new E
        {
            ConsumerID = con.ID,
            OrganizationID = con.OrganizationID,
            StartDate = ecew.StartDate,
            EndDate = ecew.EndDate,
            Deleted = ecew.Deleted
        }).ToList();
    return results;
}
```

Here is the dto class

```
public class E : ILzDto
{
  public int ConsumerID { get; set; }
  public int OrganizationID { get; set; }
  public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
  public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How many items you have in `consumerIDs` parameter ? and how many record you have in the table with `Deleted=true` ?

Comment: I don't understand you are creating a list of type E but the function returns type ConsumerExchangeChangeDto -- how can this compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want Any, not contains:

```
public ICollection<ConsumerExchangeChangeDto> GetByConsumers(List<int> consumerIDs)
{
    EnrollmentReportingModel db = (EnrollmentReportingModel)Context.DbContext;
    var results = (from ecew in db.A
        join ecewe in db.B on ecew.ID 
        equals ecewe.ExchangeChangeEnrollmentWindowID into temp
        from j in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join cecr in db.C on ecew.ConsumerExchangeChangeRequestID equals cecr.ID
        where consumerIDs.Any(x => x == cecr.ConsumerID) && !ecew.Deleted
        select new E
        {
            ConsumerID = cecr.ConsumerID,
            OrganizationID = con.OrganizationID,
            StartDate = ecew.StartDate,
            EndDate = ecew.EndDate,
            Deleted = false 
        }).ToList();
    return results;
}
```